# Dynamic function using combinations (Tuples?) of vector elements

Tags: table, tuples

I have two vectors p={p1,p2,...,pK} and q={q1,q2,...,qK} of size K. I would like to create a function which is dynamic in the sense that its definition depends on K because it uses all cross-terms (keeping one term constant) which can possibly be created with these two vectors.

As an example, for K=2 and keeping the term p1 constant, and assuming some other function g is already apropriately defined, I wish to create the following function fp1:

```
fp1:=p2*q1*q2*g[p2,q1,q2]
    +(1-p2)*q1*q2*g[1-p2,q1,q2]
    +p2*(1-q1)*q2*g[p2,1-q1,q2]
    +(1-p2)*(1-q1)*q2*g[1-p2,1-q1,q2]
    +p2*q1*(1-q2)*g[p2,q1,1-q2]
    +(1-p2)*q1*(1-q2)*g[1-p2,q1,1-q2]
    +p2*(1-q1)*(1-q2)*g[p2,1-q1,1-q2]
    +(1-p2)*(1-q1)*(1-q2)*g[1-p2,1-q1,1-q2]
```

Edit thanks to the comment by @march: I forgot to mention that each variable can have two values 0 and 1. In this example, since p1 is the "reference" (or "constant"), we get the 8 following cross products for the two values of p2, q1 and q2: {p2,1-p2}X{q1,1-q1}X{q2,1-q2}. For K=3, I would thus expect there to be the sum of 2^5 terms for the 5 variables {p2,p3,q1,q2,q3}.

How can I achieve these combinations for any K? How about if I want to create equivalent combinations but using three vectors p, q and r instead of the two above p and q?

I have not been able to get very far, but the following code defines my vectors in preparation of the cross products:

```
K=2;
pk=Table[p[k], {k, 2, K}];
qk=Table[q[k], {k, K}];
```

It also seems to me that Tuples might help, but I have not figured out how...

I am a Mathematica novice so do please do not hesitate to provide other approaches if mine seems incorrect or poor practice.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the general structure of the expression is supposed to be.  One example is good, but maybe a second example or a more complete description of what you're looking for is necessary to understand what you're trying to do.  For instance, it's not clear what "p1 is a constant" really means.  Please edit your post to include this extra information.

Comment: That said, does this work? `Clear[p, q];
n = 2;
ps = Array[p, n - 1, 2];
qs = Array[q, n];
elems = Subsets[Join[ps, qs, 1 - qs, 1 - ps], {2 n - 1}];
Times @@ # g @@ # & /@ elems // Total`

Comment: @march Thanks, I have edited the post to attempt to be more specific. I will try your suggestion as soon as I get back to my computer.

Comment: @march your suggested code does not work for my purposes: right off the bat, it seems to create more combinations, 20 in all, instead of the expected 8. Two problems I notice: 1. among those combinations are mixes of p2 and (1-p2), whereas it should be one or the other, and 2. the placement of arguments in g should be for (p2,q1,q2) in that order, whereas the order seems to have permutations as well.

Comment: What if you replaced the `Subsets` line with `Tuples@Transpose[{Join[qs, ps], 1 - 
Join[qs, ps]}]`?

Comment: @march yes, this does seem to work, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
fp1[p_, q_] := Module[{el = Join[p, q], t},
  t = Function[x, el /. Thread[x -> 1 - x]] /@ Subsets[el];
  (Times @@ # g @@ #) & /@ t
  ]
```

E.g. with K=2:

```
K = 2;
pk = Table[p[k], {k, 2, K}];
qk = Table[q[k], {k, K}];
fp1[pk, qk] // TableForm
```

[image]

Or a bit more complicated with K=3:

[image]

Comment: This works as specified (provided we use Total at the end), thanks! The line `Function[x, el /. Thread[x -> 1 - x]] /@ Subsets[el]` was a bit tough for me to understand but I think I got it :)

Comment: Thread[x -> 1 - x] creates a replacement rule that replaces all elements x in the subset by  x and 1-x. This rule is then applied to el.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version from the comments, wrapped up in a function.

```
Clear[p, q, g]
fp1[n_] := Module[{ps = Array[p, n - 1, 2], qs = Array[q, n]},
             Times @@ # g @@ # & /@ Tuples@Transpose[{Join[qs, ps], 1 - Join[qs, ps]}] // Total
            ]
```